# django celery - tasks thru django admin

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to set up celery with django.

all settings are set up and it is working if i start the task manuelly. (all happening in my local dev server)

```
mytask.apply_async()
```

then I tried to set up some tasks in admin. i set mytask to run every 5 minutes to just test.

but after 5 minutes, nothing is happening. what should be done more to get this thing work?

Comment: Is the Celery worker actually running?

Comment: @MatthewDaly yes, i started ``python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info``

Comment: @MatthewDaly what is actually celerybeat? i never used it sofar, do I need it now?

Comment: I've never used Celerybeat either. In production I use Supervisor to run the Celery worker

Comment: Also, is your message queue up and running? RabbitMQ can be a pain to configure

Comment: @MatthewDaly my next pain is to configure this thing in production. I read the supervisor docs, but it is confusing because many important pieces are everywhere and logically not put together. could you pls help me with supervisor? I thought i will insert it into uwsgi as daemon which also could work right?

Comment: You should check out http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/ for a good description of setting up Celery with Supervisor

Comment: now, the celery beat is sending the due task but the task is not executed. very weird. i think the broker isnot working properly

Comment: I suggest you use something like ipdb to debug the task itself - sounds like that would be the best approach to take

Answer (score 0):

I know It's a little late. But for the sake of answering your question.

Django-celery-beat needs to be installed via pip to run periodic tasks. After installing it, make migrations and migrate.

settings.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djcelery',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'taskname'
]

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER='djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
#BROKER_URL = 'django://'
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost'
from celery.schedules import crontab
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add': {
       'task': 'proj.taskfilename.taskname',
       'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='*'),
       'args': (5,5)
    }
}
```

This makes the task run every 1 hour.

To run the task automatically, we need to run both Worker and beat in separate terminals. Open two terminals in manage.py's location of project and run each command in one terminal.

```
celery -A proj worker -l info
celery -A proj beat -l info
```

worker keeps waiting for next task on queue. beat sends periodic tasks to queue. Worker runs them asynchronously.

Or you can run it from one terminal:

```
celery -A proj worker -B -l info
```

hope this helps.